# What does #define __UNUSED__ do?

Tags: c, macros

I am going through a C code and I found something like this:

```
#define __UNUSED__
  char buf[MAX_BUF_LENGHT];
  int errors=0;
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Probably the __UNUSED__ define is used in other files.

Comment: Could you please show an actual use of this macro in your code?

Comment: I've seen `__attribute__((unused))` which is sort of standard. I suspect this one is non-standard.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Attributes are non-standard and recognised by gcc and clang. The `__UNUSED__` macro probably resolves to an attribute for compilers that understand it and to nothing otherwise. (If it were a special macro defined by the compiler, as the two leading underscores suggest, there wouldn't be the need to explicitly define it.)

Comment: This practice is effective when you have functions that requires parameters that are of no interest to actual code. In you case it defines as not used a buffer of chars that is evidently required by the function to work. The use of macro makes quite visible that.

Comment: It means the writer of your code does not know how to spell "length".

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware that `__UNUSED__` is a predefined preprocessor symbol. So it must be a user defined symbol.

I myself have sometimes (test) code or obsolete code in a c-file that I mark-out with `#ifdef BLIEP` (and `BLIEP` is normally not defined), but can put it back into compilation by placing a `#define BLIEP`. Probably the original author of this code did something similar with `__UNUSED__`.